# Google SEO - How to get your website search result like this?

Tags: php, search, seo

Hi I am just wondering what must I do to get search result like this when entering my website on google and what is this technique called and what code do I need to add into my website ?

[image]

Comment: This is off-topic. You probably get that if you pay Google.

Comment: im sorry did i post this wrong ? cannot edit the topic

Comment: Links Link Linki Links links links this is the answerd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're called sitelinks: https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334

How to get it to show up isn't simple though, you need to set your site layout up in a way that Google recognises.

Comment: ahhh ok thanks cody I'll do some research from there !

Answer (score 0):

This is automatic, when searching for a specific brand. Try any brand you can think of - if I search for my local pizza shop, I get the same display.

Comment: so no need to do something / add code in my website to generate that kind of result ? thanks

Comment: it's happened automatically for all the sites i've made, including personal sites with really crappy navigation structure. as long as there is some structure, with pages named and linked appropriately, it should happen when google crawls your page.

Comment: ic, can i know your personal site ? just for example thanks zenkaty !

Comment: sure, just google "zen mousery"